# React native search issues - search results return 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, search

I'm trying to build a movie search app using the OMDB API. I have the majority of the app working as desired - except for the search functionality. Every time I go to search, the result will display as the movie 'undefined' (surprisingly a real movie).

[Search result displays as the movie 'undefined'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8edZ.png)

Does anyone have any ideas why? I'm thinking it has everything to do with the line `this.props.onSearch(e.target.value);` in `handleSubmit` but I'm not sure what to change there. Please forgive any super obvious mistakes - I'm a react newbie.

Here is my code:

```js
<!-----Search.js----->

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import MoviesList from './MoviesList';

class Search extends React.Component {

    state = {
        searchText: ''
    }

    onSearchChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            searchText: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onSearch(e.target.value);
        e.currentTarget.reset();
        console.log(e.target.value);
        // alert('search submitted!')
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <form className="search-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="search"
                    onChange={this.onSearchChange}
                    name="search"
                    value={this.state.searchText}
                    placeholder="Search..." />
                <button className="search-button" type="submit" id="submit">Go!</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Search;

<!------MoviesList.js----->

import React from 'react';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Search from './Search';

const MoviesList = props =>

    <ul>
        {props.results.map((result, index) =>
            <li key={index}>
            <b>{result.Title}</b> - <strong>{result.Year}</strong>
            <p>{result.Plot}</p>
            </li>
        )}
    </ul>

export default MoviesList;


<!----App.js----->

import React from 'react';
import {Button, SectionList, StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Search from './Search'
import MoviesList from './MoviesList'

const API_KEY = "xxxx";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      results: [],
      isLoading: true,
      movie: "tt3896198"
    };
    this.APIURL = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?page=3&t=${this.state.searchText}&apikey=${API_KEY}`;
  }

  searchMovies = (t = 'inception') => {
    // alert('search movies!')
    fetch(this.APIURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const updateMovies = this.state.results;
        updateMovies.push(data);
        this.setState({
          results: updateMovies,
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error fetching and parsing', error);
      });
        // console.log(this.state.results);
    }

    getMovies = async() => {
      alert('get movies!')
      fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?&i=${
       this.state.movie}&apikey=${API_KEY}`)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data)
          const importMovies = this.state.results;
          importMovies.push(data);
          this.setState({
            results:importMovies,
          })
        });
    }


  componentWillMount() {
    this.getMovies()
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className = "App">
        <Search onSearch = {this.searchMovies} />
        <div>
          {
            (this.state.loading) ? <p>Loading</p> :<MoviesList results={this.state.results} />
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you send what the variable results prints out?

Comment: Hey @thodwris, here's the link to the image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8edZ.png

Comment: I mean the actual object of results

Comment: hey @thodwris, ah - of course! Here's is what is printed in the browser console. Don't know whether it's of much help - https://www.screencast.com/t/fn4z4hRtmL.